# Cannot access request after importing urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am using the code below that was a solution to a very similar question. Still am getting an `AttributeError` for `request`:

```
import urllib

u2 = urllib.request.urlopen('http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=aapl&ql=1')
junk = u2.read()
print(junk)
```

Comment: The next time post the *full traceback* of the error. Moreover use `inline code` when referencing variables/classes etc inside the code. You didn't do any of this and it wasn't obvious that the `AttributeError` you mentioned was related to the `u2 = ...` line and not the second one.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it. Check the documentation for [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request)

```
import urllib.request

u2 = urllib.request.Request('http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=aapl&ql=1')
with urllib.request.urlopen(u2) as response:
     junk = response.read()

print(junk)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `request`

```
from urllib import request
```